# Background image on <li> becomes background instead of becoming list bullet

Tags: html, css

So I want a picture to become a bullet for my list.
I want to use a background image to become a bullet. But it becomes the background of the item.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50')
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

It must be done with a `background-image` and not with a `list-style-image`

What do I need to change?

Comment: Please check the update to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `list-style-image` to use an image instead the regular bullets

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image
>
> The list-style-image CSS property sets an image to be used as the list item marker.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50')
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**If the idea is to fake a bullet via background**, then `background-size` and `background-position` will be required. Here below an example using the shorthands syntaxe for `background`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50') 0 50% / 1em 1em no-repeat;
  padding-left:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But someone asked me to do it with a background image.

Comment: @dmarinus, then you clarify this in the question ;) I added a snippet using a background image

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use the background-image property, here is a working example:

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

li {
 background-image: url(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/edge.40018f6a.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 .4em;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example using the list-style-image CSS property

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50')
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `list-style-image` of the `ul`

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50')
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```